# Dynamically change ApolloClient URL on Android

Tags: android, apollo-client

In my Android app, the user can change the base URL of the GraphQL server at runtime.
Is there a way with the ApolloClient to do what you can do with the `@Url` annotation in Retrofit?
In other words, is it possible to use a different base URL without having to rebuild the entire ApolloClient?

Comment: Hey Kingston, were you able to find any way of doing this?

Comment: I didn’t unfortunately